# Convert NVP SQL Table to XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xpath

I have a table in containing name-value pairs. I want to serialized the name value pairs into an xml structure with a single element for each name-value-pair with the `[Name]` column as the xml element name, and the `[Value]` column as the content of the XML node.

e.g. given the following sample data...

```
;with nvp (Name, Value) as
(
    select 'Food', 'Tacos' union all
    select 'Height', '5''9"' union all
    select 'Value', '3.141'
)
select *
from nvp
```

I want an xml chunk that looks like this:

```
<root>
    <Food>Tacos</Food>
    <Height>5'9"</Height>
    <Value>3.141</Value>
</root>
```

When I tried FOR XML PATH I get something like below, which is NOT what I want.

```
<root>
  <Name>Food</Name>
  <Value>Tacos</Value>
</root>
<root>
  <Name>Height</Name>
  <Value>5'9"</Value>
</root>
<root>
  <Name>Value</Name>
  <Value>3.141</Value>
</root>
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a transpose of rows to columns before convert into `XML`.

Also mention the Root name in `Xml path()`

```
;WITH nvp (NAME, Valued)
     AS (SELECT 'Food', 'Tacos'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Height', '5''9"'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Value', '3.141')
SELECT *
FROM   nvp
       PIVOT (Max(valued)
             FOR NAME IN ([Food],
                          [Height],
                          [Value])) pv
FOR xml path('root')
```

**Result:**

```
<root>
  <Food>Tacos</Food>
  <Height>5'9"</Height>
  <Value>3.141</Value>
</root>
```